# PostgreSQL - How to get data grouped by two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count the number of IP addresses for a certain IP and a date range for example `where date = 2017-12-01 and IP = '122.12.168.105'`.

I expect to get 3 columns: a date, count of IPs for the date and the IP itself:

```
|    the_date  |count|       IP        |
|   2017-12-01 | 155 | 122.12.168.105  |
```

For now I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ip), ip 
FROM my_db.logs
GROUP BY ip 
LIMIT 100;
```

But it returns me just a count for every IP. How do I also group by date?

When I'm trying to add a date into the `SELECT` statement there's an error stating that the the_date must be in the `GROUP_BY` clause. But how should I group IPs then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to count the number of IP addresses for a certain IP and a date range for example where date = 2017-12-01 and IP = '122.12.168.105'.

Just add the filter as a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(ip) as cnt, ip 
FROM my_db.logs
WHERE
    my_date = to_date('2017-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
    AND ip = '122.12.168.105'
GROUP BY ip 
LIMIT 100;
```

This will return one row with the number of times a given IP appears in the logs for a given date, like :

```
CNT | IP
15  | 122.12.168.105
```

> How do I also group by date?

If you want to return more (non aggregated) columns, you need to add them in the `GROUP BY` clause as you add them to the `SELECT` :

```
SELECT COUNT(ip) as cnt, ip, my_date
FROM my_db.logs
WHERE
    my_date = to_date('2017-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
    AND ip = '122.12.168.105'
GROUP BY ip, my_date
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: but how do I also get the date returned?

Answer (score 3):

Add `the_date` into grouping statement:

```
SELECT the_date, COUNT(1), ip 
FROM my_db.logs
GROUP BY the_date, ip
LIMIT 100;
```

If the column name is `date` (not `the_date`), you must use double quotes becuase `date` is [a reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-keywords-appendix.html):

```
SELECT "date", COUNT(1), ip 
FROM my_db.logs
GROUP BY "date", ip
LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `date` to the `group by`:

```
SELECT the_date, ip, COUNT(ip)
FROM my_db.logs
GROUP BY the_date, ip
LIMIT 100;
```

Normally, when using `LIMIT` you would have an `ORDER BY`.  For instance, to get the most common ip/date combinations:

```
SELECT the_date, ip, COUNT(*)
FROM my_db.logs
GROUP BY the_date, ip
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: `Normally, when using LIMIT you would have a GROUP BY` Do You mean `ORDER BY` ?